# jquery-datatables-editable customization

Tags: jquery, datatables

i use the [jquery-datatables-editable](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/Customization) plugin. i use the add button which popups a form . i see this form could be customized for its UI using the oAddNewRowFormOptions parameter in plugin initialization. however i want to use the [jquery tools validator](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html) to validate form fields instead of the jquery.validate plugin that the above datatables-editable plugin use by default.

is there a parameter option that i could specify in plugin init so it uses another validator i.e the validator from [jquery tools validator](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html)?

another question is:

can we have the add button (from above plugin) adds a new table inline editable row instead of the popup form?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the event fnOnAdding wich is called just after the Ok button click to validate your form.

http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/events.html

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
                    sDeleteURL: "DeleteData.php",
        sAddURL: "AddData.php",
                    fnOnAdding: function()
            {   
                $("#trace").append("Adding new record");
                return true;
            },
        });

     } );
```